# Subfigure slow compilation

Tags: compiling, subfloats

I'm using graphicx and subcaption to have 4 images arranged in a two-row grid, three at the top and one at the bottom. The problem is the latex file takes around 50 seconds to compile in a Win10 machine with TexMaker, alternatively, it reaches the compile time limit in overleaf.

What could be improved to make it faster? MWE:

[Black Image Figure "FigureAN" for the MWE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxqhu.jpg)

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figureAN}
    \caption{Figure A}
    \label{fig:figureA}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figureAN}
    \caption{Figure B}
    \label{fig:figureB}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.32\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figureAN}
    \caption{Figure C}
    \label{fig:figureC}
\end{subfigure}
\\[2ex]
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{figureAN}
    \caption{Figure D}
    \label{fig:figureD}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure A, B, C, D.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I replace your image "figureAN" with example image (provided by package `graphicx`, the compilation time on my (old) PC with Windows 10 and MikTeX 64-bit, is negligible small ...

Comment: `subfigure` takes essentially no time (it will take more time to load the images from teh filesystem that to do the figure processing) so I can only assume that your images are _massive_. ? what is the filesize of your images?

Comment: Not really: 825 KB, 678 KB, 2677 KB and 305 KB. All png files.